# is it possible to compare 7 tables in hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

i have a 7 tables like A,B,C,D,E,F,G and all are having same schema,
my primary key is empid, 
just an example 10001 is my empid, now i want to check where all 7 tables are having 10001 empid, 
if yes then select data fields from table which has last modified date and time, take that data fields and compare with all other 6 tables are having same data,
 if data mismatch, select that row from table and store it in 1 temp table.

Comment: Counting all distinct empid in all 7 tables in one query can be done using UNION ALL. However, I think that providing code that you have already tried would help solving your issue.

Comment: I think what you need is to create UNION ALL subquery and then do a RANK to get the latest value. You can also you LEAD/LAG to compare the previous data and see if the data has changed.

Comment: Based on the post you've made, I would recommend spending some time reading documentation in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) so that you have the best chance at getting your question answered.